# Dismissing items from news feed in my app. Android - Java

Tags: android, storage, feed

I have made an app which shows users news articles in a news feed. I would like them to be able to 'dismiss' articles they have already read. What would the best way be to let the application know which articles have been read and should no longer display and which should?

I have thought about storing articles data in a file and populating the feed. When the user removes an item from the feed it will rewrite the file (thus no longer containing the dismissed article). The articles have varying layouts and contain images... What is the best/smartest or fastest way for me to handle 'read'-articles?

I don't need any code, just ideas on how to handle it?

Comment: have you got your answer I have similar issue with my app

Comment: This is a bit of a late answer but might still be helpful. In the end I gave each new article an ID (eg. 0, 1, 2  etc.). An array with these codes would be pulled from the server. Read articles (stored in a local file) would be removed from the array by removing the ID. Then a request of the remaining articles are made (I also removed the articles that are currently in the feed). If that helps...